# Extended Custom theme problem

Tags: magento2, theme, custom

I extend blank theme but on static content deploy I get a lot of errors on missing less variables

```
variable @icon-error is undefined in file .... in _theme.less
```

having structure

```
vendor/
--theme
---web
---Magento_Theme
----web
------css
-------source
----css
------source
-------_buttons.less
-------_navigation.less
```

How do I debug this issue?

Comment: Post the file structure of your custom theme (specifically `.less` files). Normally I'd point you to http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-debugging but I suspect you did a file override that is preventing the default `@import`s

Comment: I just added how looks my folder stucture and thanks for feedback but is still not clear how to organize web folder on extend blank theme

Comment: `_theme.less` is (or, should be) an empty file in the default themes. Make sure you didn't accidentally edit any of the files in the blank theme.  If you're getting an error pointing to `_theme.less`, that suggests to me you edited something in the default blank theme.

Also, to clear up how the file structure should be... Just a couple of days ago, I wrote a short guide on how to organize `.less` files, and maybe that will help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110164/how-do-you-override-less-in-a-custom-theme/110165#110165

Comment: finally is getting compiled after I deleted view_preprocessed but now I get no css styling

Comment: Before continuing, make sure your site is in development mode, and I would recommend changing to client-side LESS compilation as described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html this will make it easier to see your changes.

Comment: Then clear your `view_preprocessed` and `pub/static` before reloading and see if you get any errors

Comment: hm thanks I switched to dev and clientside compilation I get de_DE/css/styles-l.css not found so needs to be created  some less ?

Comment: `styles-l` is  normally automatically included, unless you changed some other files. You could always copy-paste `styles-l.less` from blank too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38232/discussion-between-fefe-and-andyjv).