# Magento 2: How to override gallery.css?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides, less, gallery

I want to override `lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less` and some module files in

**lib/web/mage/gallery/module/*.less**

I need to override them because I want to change the style of product gallery images.

How to override or Are there any other way to "settle the question"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can override the less file `lib` in our custom theme. Put this file under `web` folder:

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
```

and add `mage/gallery/gallery` in `PROJECT/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` (or `PROJECT/dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes/themes.js` for magento 2.2) to make grunt compiling it as well.

Comment: Thanks you for answer, but I try it, seem it not work.
I had already remove cache and static files, deploy again, It didn't work.

Comment: You should read more: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110164/how-do-you-override-less-in-a-custom-theme

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But I read a check it agian, They are only work with less files in lib/web/css/source.
Can you please help me check again?

Comment: @MrTim you should try `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/web/css/source/lib/mage/gallery/gallery.less`

Comment: Thanks in advanced. I had try it, when I deploy it said that: 
`Compilation from source: /app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme_name}/web/css/source/lib/mage/gallery/gallery.less

Compilation from source:
frontend/{Vendor}/{theme_name}/en_US/css/source/lib/mage/gallery/gallery.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/{Vendor}/{theme_name}/en_US/css/source/lib/mage/gallery/module/_variables.less'`

Comment: Ok! Let's me check again.

Comment: @MrTim I has just checked, my current answer can work.

Comment: Thank you and very sorry @Khoa. I has checked again, It working well.

Comment: Hi, you must add and  **'mage/gallery/gallery'** in **PROJECT/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js** in your theme configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In your custom config file for Grunt add path to gallery file: 'mage/gallery/gallery' along with 'css/styles-m' and 'css/styles-l'