# UI library less override

Tags: magento2, menu, submenu, ui-library

I need to override a less file in `/lib/web/css/source/lib/` because `_navigation.less` contains a mixin `.lib-main-navigation-desktop()` which use some `!important` rules that brooke the submenu positioning.

What is the "right" way to do it?

Comment: Take a look: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/147915/33057

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to add

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/web/css/source/lib/_navigation.less
```