# How Can I override vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/extjs/ext-tree.js file for backend in magneto2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, base

How Can I override **`vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/extjs/ext-tree.js`** file for backend? I want to customize this file which will effect on backend admin

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
app/design/adminhtml/{Vendor}/{Theme}/web/extjs/ext-tree.js
```

And After run below commnads :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

I have got answer this link :-

**[Magento 2 How to override vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/_navigation.less?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147911/magento-2-how-to-override-vendor-magento-magento2-base-lib-web-css-source-lib-n)**