# How to correctly add my less file to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, less

1. Create theme `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/default`
2. Try add `my.less` file for impot, or add code with new class and style to `_extends.less` to `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/default/web/css/sourse`.
3. `rm -rf pub/static/*`
4. `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*`
5. `php /var/www/html/bin/magento cache:clean`
6. `php /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
7. `php /var/www/html/bin/magento cache:clean`

But this not work.
I read a lot, but I do not see a particular decision. Please write how to correctly add less file to Magento 2? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can import by using `@import` or `@magento_import` directive

1) **The @import directive rules of usage**

```
@import 'your_custom.less';
```

2) **The @magento_import directive - must be commented out with two slashes**

```
//@magento_import 'your_custom.less';
```

For example: `your_custom.less` is under `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/`

> -*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less*

```
@import 'your_custom.less';
```

You can read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Comment: I add 2 files _theme.less and _my_file.less to app/design/frontend/Vendorname/default/web/css/sourse. In _theme.less write @import 'source/_my_file.less'; Remove pub/static. Site not work, now not work all style.

Comment: You should add our custom file at the end of the file. Keep the old import files.

Comment: I save all code _theme.less and add at the end @import 'source/_my_file.less'; Maybe _theme.less not good for import.

Comment: Did you run static deploy command again?

Comment: Yep. When I return original _theme.less and static deploy command again, site work. With @import 'source/_my_file.less'; - not work.

Comment: `/_my_file.less` has any CSS code lines?

Comment: Yes, a lot code lines for slider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50763/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-sergey-eremin).