# Magento 2.1.3 Create theme

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, magento-2.1.3

I'm beginning with Magento and it's incredible that create a theme is so complicated...

I've understand that to add my css to the head I need to override a layout. So I override default_head_blocks.xml with this content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>    
        <!-- Add your own CSS files -->
        <css src="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

But this not works. Also after :
- ./bin/magento setup:upgrade
- ./bin/magento cache:flush && ./bin/magento cache:clean

Structure of my theme :
[image: structure]

Comment: The theme directory name should be lowercase - `vehicules`. I'm not sure if this is required or just a convention but try changing that.

Comment: I changed the theme directory name, remove the old and flush and it appears in admin > content > design > theme. But when in my css i try to style a template from a custom module it doesn't works...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to activate the theme :

> I managed to change the theme if you change the setting as single
>   shop.
>
> Store > Configuration > General > General > Single-Store Mode > YES
>
> content > Configuration > Edit Default theme > Smartwave Porto

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "_extend.less" file to –

> /app/design/frontend/Test/Vehicules/Magento_Theme/web/css/source

- Make sure the files name is exactly written as seen above. You can
  use this file as a standard CSS file but with additional LESS
  functionality. Naming your files is very important if you work with parent/child themes.
- Clean cache
- Read more: [How do you override LESS in a custom theme?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110164/how-do-you-override-less-in-a-custom-theme)

Comment: And all less files will be loaded ? And then when I change something in the Less file I just need to clean caches ? because from now I was using gulp to compile less filles in put in the source folder to made compressed versions in css folder :)

Comment: But why his solution about the css not works ?

Comment: All I do after doing changes in the LESS file is: php_cli bin/magento setup:upgrade and reload the page. I'm not an expert but I guess there is also an easier way to do it.