# Magento 2 - How to extend a custom theme which uses less variables?

Tags: magento2, theme

I have a custom theme for our onlineshop named "**Company Fresh**" which extends `Magento/luma`.

I created another theme which I named "**Company Fresh Green**".

It is **based on "Company Fresh"** but has only one difference. The background color of all sites should be **green**.

I added these files to my new theme:

---

(THEME_DIR = app/design/frontend/company/fresh_green)

#### THEME_DIR/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/company/fresh_green', __DIR__);
```

#### THEME_DIR/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Company Fresh Green</title>
    <parent>company/fresh</parent>
</theme>
```

#### THEME_DIR/web/css/source/_extend.less

```
@import 'sites/category/_produkte';
```

#### THEME_DIR/web/css/source/sites/category/_produkte.less

```
body {
    background: green !important;
}
```

But if I compile, I get

```
Running "less:company_fresh_green" (less) task
>> NameError: variable @md is undefined in pub/static/frontend/company/fresh-green/de_DE/Magento_PageBuilder/css/source/slick/_slick.less on line 383, column 36:
>> 382     // MobileSlider
>> 383     @media screen and (max-width: (@md - 1) ){
>> 384         .pagebuilder-slider{
Warning: Error compiling pub/static/frontend/company/fresh-green/de_DE/css/styles-m.less Use --force to continue.
```

@md is defined in "Company Fresh", but my new theme does not know it. Why?

Comment: Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110164/how-do-you-override-less-in-a-custom-theme/110165#110165

Comment: It is not answering my question, it shows how to override a LESS file. I just try to use the parent less files and variables.

Comment: @Black Colors like red, green, yellow, etc do not work in less files. Use #00ff00;

Comment: @DanielIfrim, thats not true, they work of course. You can use everything that also works in CSS.

Comment: @Black I think the answer to your question you can find in [official documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/quickstart/customize-styles/). See **Extend parent styles**.

Answer (score 0):

## First possible solution

Did you try

```sh
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```

in your case

```sh
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --type="less" --locale="de_DE" --area="frontend" --theme="company/fresh_green"
```

before

```sh
grunt less:company_fresh_green
```

---

## Second possible solution

[Source](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/preprocess/#import-directive)

**`@import` directive**

You can import local and remote `.less` and `.css` files in your `.less` stylesheets by using the standard LESS `@import` directive. According to the `@import` syntax, specifying the file extension for the imported file is not mandatory. For example, the following notation is allowed:

```less
@import 'source/lib/_lib';
@import (css) 'styles';
```

But in process of resolving the file path, the application adds the `.less` extension for the imported files in all `@import` entrees. So in the processed files, the statements from the previous example will look like following:

```less
@import 'source/lib/_lib.less';
@import (css) 'styles.less';
```

As a result, the processed files are different from the source files. So in the `client-side compilation mode` or when using `grunt commands`, the application cannot use symlinks to the source files. Instead it uses the copies of processed files, and they are published to the `pub/static` directory. In case of importing CSS resources, this also results in not finding and not importing the required files.

Comment: You answered on a old version of my question. This is not the problem.

Comment: if the updated answer didn't help, it would be nice to take a look at `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`